# control form.valid from child component Angular

Tags: angular

I am creating a simple textbox component in Angular.
I want to have a validation on this textbox like if value == "xyz" then the parent component's (with form tag) form.valid should be false so that it is added in form's errors list

my textbox component's html is

```
  <input type="text">
```

i am using this component in parent component like this

```
<form #form="ngForm">
.
.
.
<app-ec-textbox  </app-ec-textbox>
```

What i want is if some types "xyz" in textbox, form validations should fail so that i can disable save button. i want to achieve it from textbox component and not from parent component. Not sure i am asking sensible question.

```
 <button [disabled]="!form.valid></button>
```

Comment: You might want to read up on ControlValueAccessor components

Comment: if you are open to it, I would suggest reactive forms, very easy to use with child components. Just passing down a formcontrol to the child and everything is taken care of. Just a suggestion.